# How to make a Textfield with multiple lines and cursor start at top-left?

Tags: swiftui

I'm studying SwiftUI and when I using TextField then I have a problem with TextField's cursor is still at left-center of TextField's area.
How can I set it to left-top of TextField area.
Thanks!

This is my code:

```
TextField("What is your mind?", text: $statusContent)
                    .clipped()
                    .frame(height: 100, alignment: .leading)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```